# Retrieve all users even if there is no user log entries

Tags: mysql, pdo, left-join

I want this query to show all users no matter what. And the calculate number of logins that happened in a certain time period (or just retun zero if there are no entries).

Right now, it only show users that have entries in the log in that time period.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_log.type) AS logins,
    users.name,
    users.email,
    users.user_id
FROM 
    users
LEFT JOIN
    user_log
ON
    users.user_id = user_log.user_id
WHERE
    user_log.type = 8
AND
    user_log.date >= :from
AND
    user_log.date <= :to
GROUP BY
    users.user_id
```

user_log.type = 8 means the log entry is a login

:from is a timestamp with the start date

:to is a timestamp with the end date

I use PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're misusing a pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. You'll have a hard time debugging.  So you need to `GROUP BY users.name, users.email. users.id`.

The way your query is written, with items from your `LEFT JOIN`ed table in your `WHERE` clause, converts `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`. So you're losing the unmatched rows from your first table.

Move those `WHERE` items to the `ON` clause and things will work the way you want.  Like so.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_log.type) AS logins,
    users.name,
    users.email,
    users.user_id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_log
ON (
     users.user_id = user_log.user_id
AND
    user_log.type = 8
AND
    user_log.date >= :from
AND
    user_log.date <= :to
)
GROUP BY
    users.name, users.email. users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a where constraint on the second table with a LEFT JOIN, you'll have the same result as if you have used an INNER JOIN, because you don't allow NULL value.

Here a solution you can try, using a subrequest :

```
SELECT users.name,
    users.email,
    users.user_id,
    IF (logins IS NOT NULL, logins, 0) AS logins
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(type) AS logins
    FROM user_log
    WHERE
        type = 8
    AND
        date >= :from
    AND
        date <= :to
    GROUP BY
        user_id
    ) AS l ON l.user_id = users.user_id
```